# JavaScript: how do I flatten an object like this

Tags: javascript

how do we implement a util `flatten` to flat this

```js
myMap = {
  'a': 5,
  'b': 6,
  'c': {
    'f': 9,
    'g': {
      'm': 17,
      'n': 3
    }
  }
}
```

to

```js
flatten(myMap) = {
  'a': 5,
  'b': 6,
‍‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‌‍‍ 'c.f': 9,
  'c.g.m': 17,
  'c.g.n': 3,
}
```

?

I found here is an implementation https://github.com/lukeed/flattie/blob/master/src/index.js but I couldn't understand the code. Can someone please give me a more readable version?

Comment: It's quite clear and straight-forward in my opinion. Can you please explain what exactly the issue is, so we can help clear it up?

Comment: It is basically traversing a tree, and write down the whole path of every leaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is perhaps a slightly simpler version:

```js
const inputObject = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  c: {
    f: 9,
    g: {
      m: 17,
      n: 3
    }
  }
}

function flatten(input, keys = [], output = {}) {
  for (key in input) {
    const value = input[key]
    const combinedKeys = [...keys, key]

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      output = flatten(value, combinedKeys, output)
    } else {
      output[combinedKeys.join('.')] = value
    }
  }
  return output
}

console.log(flatten(inputObject))
/* Logs:
 * {
 *   "a": 5,
 *   "b": 6,
 *   "c.f": 9,
 *   "c.g.m": 17,
 *   "c.g.n": 3
 * }
 */
```

The idea is to recursively look at all properties of the object and build a `.`-separated key as we go deeper until we reach a leaf value.

You can read more about recursive functions here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-recursion-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```js
myMap = {
  'a': 5,
  'b': 6,
  'c': {
    'f': 9,
    'g': {
      'm': 17,
      'n': 3
    }
  }
}

function flatten(obj, pKey = null, res = {}) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    const name = pKey ? `${pKey}.${key}` : key;
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      flatten(obj[key], name, res);
    } else {
      res[name] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(flatten(myMap))
```

you can use it by `flatten(myMap)`. Actually, it's simple, but sometimes it makes confusion. how it works is by looping then checking, if it is an object then calling itself again (recursive) to create a key object deeply and if not then create a key object until there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
// Declare an object
myMap = {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 6,
    'c': {
      'f': 9,
      'g': {
         'm': 17,
         'n': 3
  }
 }
}
// Declare a flatten function that takes
// object as parameter and returns the
// flatten object
const flattenObj = (myMap) => {

// The object which contains the
// final result
let result = {};

// loop through the object "ob"
for (const i in myMap) {

    // We check the type of the i using
    // typeof() function and recursively
    // call the function again
    if ((typeof myMap[i]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(myMap[i])) {
        const temp = flattenObj(myMa**strong text**p[i]);
        for (const j in temp) {

            // Store temp in result
            result[i + '.' + j] = temp[j];
        }
    }

    // Else store ob[i] in result directly
    else {
        result[i] = myMap[i];
    }
}
return result;
};

console.log(flattenObj(myMap));
```